# Angular Cordova Project (Android) doesn't open Razorpay external page (Enter OTP/ Enter Login credential page)

Tags: android, html, angular, cordova

Razor pay works properly when opening in a browser but when i convert the project into an android app, external page which is supposed to be opened to submit OTP doesn't show up. I understand i need an inAppBrowser to open the link but it is not controlled by me. Razorpay will open the link automatically when the user chooses card payment or internet banking. How to solve this? please help!

**window-ref.service.ts**

```
    import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
// declare var cordova:any;

export interface ICustomWindow extends Window {
  __custom_global_stuff: string;
}

function getWindow(): any {
  return window;
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class WindowRefService {

  get nativeWindow(): ICustomWindow {
    return getWindow();
  }
}
```

**app.component.ts**

```
constructor(private winRef: WindowRefService) {
    this._window = this.winRef.nativeWindow;
  }

private _window: ICustomWindow;
  public rzp: any;
  public options: any = {
    key: 'KEY', // add razorpay key here
    name: 'Bunto Couriers Pvt. Ltd.',
    description: 'Delivery Fee',
    amount: this.price*100, // razorpay takes amount in paisa
    prefill: {
      name: '',
      email: '', // add your email id
    },
    image: 'https://isell-bunto.000webhostapp.com/assets/img/loader.png', 
    notes: {},
    theme: {
      color: '#3880FG'
    },
    handler: this.paymentHandler.bind(this),
    modal: {
      ondismiss: (() => {
        this.zone.run(() => {
          // add current page routing if payment fails
          this.toastr.error("Payment Error!");
        })
      })
    }
  };

initPay(): void {
    this.rzp = new this.winRef.nativeWindow['Razorpay'](this.options);
    this.rzp.open();
  }

  paymentHandler(res: any) {
    this.zone.run(() => {
      // add API call here
      console.log(res);
    });
  }
```

[this is a pop up window which opens fine in both browser and in android app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aWkME.png)
[this external page doesn't show up in the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/afS74.png)
[in the app, this is as far as it goes. external url doesn't open after this stage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CtEpj.png)

Comment: Are you using the Javascript SDK for Razor? Or the Cordova plugin?

Comment: i am using javascript SDK

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how the Javascript library will work while we don't have the control over showing it using the InAppBrowser.

For this, I really suggest to use the native Cordova Razorpay plugin for more compatibility and stability: https://github.com/razorpay/razorpay-cordova

You can check their sample apps (Cordova and Ionic)

Add command: `cordova plugin add https://github.com/razorpay/razorpay-cordova.git --save`

```
var options = {
  description: 'Credits towards consultation',
  image: 'https://i.imgur.com/3g7nmJC.png',
  currency: 'INR',
  key: 'rzp_test_1DP5mmOlF5G5ag',
  order_id: 'order_7HtFNLS98dSj8x',
  amount: '5000',
  name: 'foo',
  theme: {
    color: '#F37254'
  }
}

var successCallback = function(success) {
  alert('payment_id: ' + success.razorpay_payment_id)
  var orderId = success.razorpay_order_id
  var signature = success.razorpay_signature
}

var cancelCallback = function(error) {
  alert(error.description + ' (Error '+error.code+')')
}

RazorpayCheckout.on('payment.success', successCallback)
RazorpayCheckout.on('payment.cancel', cancelCallback)
RazorpayCheckout.open(options)
```

Comment: thanks for the info. i did this but i am getting an error. RazorpayCheckout is not defined. Can you please help?

Link -
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63762182/razorpay-integration-in-cordova-razorpaycheckout-is-not-defined