# Razorpay integration in cordova [RazorPayCheckout is not defined]

Tags: angular, typescript, cordova, ionic-framework, razorpay

i am getting RazorPayCheckout is not defined error. there are few similar questions on stackoverflow but no answers. please help. thanks in advance

**app.component.html**

```
 <button (click)="payWithRazor()">Proceed to Pay</button>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
payWithRazor() {
    var options = {
      key: 'KEY', // add razorpay key here
      name: 'Bunto Couriers Pvt. Ltd.',
      description: 'Delivery Fee',
      amount: this.price*100, // razorpay takes amount in paisa
      prefill: {
        name: '',
        email: '', // add your email id
      },
      image: 'link', 
      notes: {},
      theme: {
        color: '#00FF00'
      },
      modal: {
        ondismiss: (() => {
          this.zone.run(() => {
            // add current page routing if payment fail
          })
        })
      }
    };

    var successCallback = function (payment_id) {
      alert('payment_id: ' + payment_id);
    };

    var cancelCallback = function (error) {
      alert(error.description + ' (Error ' + error.code + ')');
    };
    RazorpayCheckout.on('payment.success', successCallback);
    RazorpayCheckout.on('payment.cancel', cancelCallback);
    RazorpayCheckout.open(options);
    // RazorpayCheckout.open(options, successCallback, cancelCallback);
  }
```

**declaration.d.ts**

```
declare module '*';

declare var RazorpayCheckout: any;
```

Comment: i have added RazorPay plugin for cordova

Comment: Are you sure you are using the plugin after the [platform.ready](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/api/platform/Platform/#ready)? also, make sure that the plugin was installed correctly without errors

Comment: any luck on this as i am getting same issue

Answer (score 0):

Add

Cordova platform add browser

It would download the similar environment where Cordova app would run in a browser but with features and functionality of a near native device
Then do

Cordova build android

Post it run

Cordova run browser

A pop browser will open seperately and the Cordova app would be launched . Razorpay would detect as a Cordova complaint and run without hiccups